# Scala: Test whether Any variable can be iterated over

Tags: scala

I want to make a function that checks whether a variable of type `Any` can be iterated over.

```
def checkIterable(v: Any): Boolean = {
    // match with something?
}
```

Then I would be able to use it like:

```
if (checkIterable(something)) {
    for (s <- something) {
        // do something with each element s of something
    }
}
```

This should return true for variables of type `Array`, `List`, `Seq`, and `Iterable`, basically any type that defines a `foreach` function (doesn't seem like I should be testing for the existence of that function, unless it's the only possible way...)

Comment: That makes sense, because `Array` is not `Iterable`. Perhaps, we could be of more help if you explained what you are really trying to do rather that starting with describing a non-working solution.

Comment: One way of checking it is to use `v.isInstanceOf[Iterable]`, but, as @Dima says, it would be better if you were more explicit about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Why do you have an `Any` in the first place?

Comment: @Dima I receive an `Any` because I'm reading in data from somewhere, and sometimes that data can be iterated over, e.g. an `Array` or a `List`. I want to be able to test whether it can be iterated over, and then do something if it can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a pattern match?

```
something match {
  case xs: Iterable[_] => // do something with xs as iterable ...
  case _ => // ... that's something other
}
```

**EDIT**

Since you want to iterate over to result but don't know what's inside, the only way I can imagine is something like this:

```
def toList(x: Any): List[Any] = x match {
  case xs: Iterable[_] => xs.toList
  case xs: Array[_] => xs.toList
  case _ => List.empty
}
```

This way, no matter whats your input, you will get a `List` back and can iterate over it. If it was not iterable, it will be an empty List.

```
toList("foo")        // List[Any] = List()
toList(List(1, 2, 3) // List[Any] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I tried at first, but it only works for a variable of type `Iterable`, and not `Array` or `List`, which can also be iterated over.

Comment: I've updated my answer, not the best but should work.

Comment: I considered this as well but wouldn't I have to match against every type that is iterable? `Array`, `List`, `Seq`, `Iterable`, `ListBuffer`, ... I was hoping there was a general way to test whether a type supports iteration

Comment: Not exactly, because the most types are composed of other types, e.g. a `Seq` is also an `Iterable`. On the other side, if you're types are so cluttered that you can even distinguish any kind of type, you need to deal with it somewhere, e.g. some method like this. The other way would be to improve your File reading process and return properly typed instances.

Comment: Ok, I was hoping there was some parent type of all iterable sequences that I could compare against, or test whether `foreach` is defined for some given type, to have a purely general solution. Looks like that may not be possible in an elegant way. I'm not reading from a file, I'm using an API that hands over `Any` instances, so don't have control over typing them earlier on. Thanks, will accept!

Comment: There is also the upper type `Traversable`, have a look here -> http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_1.html